# Can't align table with overflow

Tags: html, html-table, overflow

I'm new to html and I'm working on designing my website.  I made a table that WAS center aligned until I put a scroll bar on it.  Now I can't get the table to center align unless I take out the scroll bar.  I'll show you what I have so far:

```
<div style="overflow: auto; height: 86px; width: 750px;">
<table
style="height: 86px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; width: 750px; text-align: left;"
border-style:="" hidden;="" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2">
  <tbody>

    TABLE CONTENT with multiple rows and two columns.
  </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

I tried several different approaches and still no luck.  It seems like it shouldn't be this hard, so I figure I'm overlooking some small but important detail.  Any help would greatly be appreciated.

Comment: Did you put a scroll bar on the table or on the div? do you want the table centered and inside a div with a scroll?

Answer (score 1):

Move the "margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto" styles to the div instead of the table.  Also, your div and table are the same size, so there won't be a scrollbar.

```
<div style="overflow: auto; height: 86px; width: 500px;margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; "> 
    <table style="height: 86px; width: 750px; text-align: left;" border-style:="" hidden;="" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2"> 
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 </td>
                <td>2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 </td>
                <td>4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div
```